# JavaScript тесты

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть код теста, и я хочу, чтобы если в тесте набралось не более 10%, то мне выводилось "плохо", а если другие результаты, то уже другие ответы

```js
$(function() {

  $('.questionForm input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    var answer = 0;
    $('#wrap').addClass('none');
    for (i = 0; i < $('.group').length; i++) {
      $('.group').eq(i).each(function(id, elem) {
        if ($(elem).find('input:checked').length != 0) {
          if ($(elem).find('input:checked').attr('value') == 1) {
            answer++;
          }
        }
      })
    }
    $("#wrap").hide();
    $(".result").show("slow", function() {
      $(".result").replaceWith("<div class='replace-container'>" + "<div class='replace'>" + "Тест пройден на: " + "<p>" + (answer / $('.group').length) * 100 + '%' + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>")
    })

    return false
  })
})
```

```css
div.questionBlock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title_js">
  <h1>Начальный уровень</h1>
</div>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <br>
    <font size="+2">
      <p align="center">
        <div class="questionBlock">
          <font size="+1">
            <br>

            <form method="POST" action="test.php" class="questionForm">
              <div class="group">
                <h3>JavaScript - это</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">Язык разметка<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">Язык программирования<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">Язык описания внешнего вида<br>
              </div>

              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript text="javascript"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript="text/javascript"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">&ltscript type="text/javascript"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript type="javascript"><br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить комментарий надо</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">использовать */<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">использовать **<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">использовать //<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">использовать &lt!--<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Как вывести слово "привет"</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="1">Через alert ('привет');<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">Через hi ('привет');<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">Через alert (привет);<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">Через alert 'привет';<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Какой из вариантов создаст переменную "a"</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0">var = a;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="1">var a;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0">$a;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0">var<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Какой вариант неправильный</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="0">
                <div class="code">
                  <pre style="background-color: #bfbfbf;color:#000"> <span style="color:#00f;font-weight:700">var</span> x;
     <span style="color:#3c4c72;font-weight:700">alert</span>(<span style="color:#0000cd">x</span>);</pre>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="1">
                <div class="code">
                  <pre style="background-color: #bfbfbf;color:#000"> <span style="color:#00f;font-weight:700">var</span> x = 10;
     <span style="color:#3c4c72;font-weight:700">alert</span>(<span style="color:#0000cd">x</span>);</pre>
                </div><br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="1">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0">4)<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="1">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0">4)<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="1">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0">4)<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="1">4)<br>
              </div>

              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" name="submit">
              <br>
              <br>
            </form>
          </font>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <span>Тест пройден на <p>0%</p></span>
  </div>
  <div class="result1">
    <span>Вы не прошли тест!</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, собственно, добавить переменную, отвечающую за процент прохождения, и в зависимости от её значения изменять код страницы с помощью функции, аргумент которой - эта самая переменная:

```js
function result(percent) {
  if (percent <= 10) return 'Плохо';
  //дальше - код для других значений
}

$(function() {

  $('.questionForm input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    var answer = 0;
    $('#wrap').addClass('none');
    for (i = 0; i < $('.group').length; i++) {
      $('.group').eq(i).each(function(id, elem) {
        if ($(elem).find('input:checked').length != 0) {
          if ($(elem).find('input:checked').attr('value') == 1) {
            answer++;
          }
        }
      })
    }
    var percent = (answer / $('.group').length) * 100;
    $("#wrap").hide();
    $(".result").show("slow", function() {
      $(".result").replaceWith("<div class='replace-container'>" + "<div class='replace'>" + "Тест пройден на: " + "<p>" + percent + '%' + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>")
      $(".result1").replaceWith("<div class='replace-container'>" + "<div class='replace'>" + "<p>" + result(percent) + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>")
    });

    return false;
  })
})
```

```css
div.questionBlock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title_js">
  <h1>Начальный уровень</h1>
</div>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <br>
    <font size="+2">
      <p align="center">
        <div class="questionBlock">
          <font size="+1">
            <br>

            <form method="POST" action="test.php" class="questionForm">
              <div class="group">
                <h3>JavaScript - это</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">Язык разметка<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">Язык программирования<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">Язык описания внешнего вида<br>
              </div>

              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript text="javascript"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript="text/javascript"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">&ltscript type="text/javascript"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript type="javascript"><br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить комментарий надо</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">использовать */<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">использовать **<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">использовать //<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">использовать &lt!--<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Как вывести слово "привет"</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="1">Через alert ('привет');<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">Через hi ('привет');<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">Через alert (привет);<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">Через alert 'привет';<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Какой из вариантов создаст переменную "a"</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0">var = a;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="1">var a;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0">$a;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0">var<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Какой вариант неправильный</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="0">
                <div class="code">
                  <pre style="background-color: #bfbfbf;color:#000"> <span style="color:#00f;font-weight:700">var</span> x;
     <span style="color:#3c4c72;font-weight:700">alert</span>(<span style="color:#0000cd">x</span>);</pre>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="1">
                <div class="code">
                  <pre style="background-color: #bfbfbf;color:#000"> <span style="color:#00f;font-weight:700">var</span> x = 10;
     <span style="color:#3c4c72;font-weight:700">alert</span>(<span style="color:#0000cd">x</span>);</pre>
                </div><br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="1">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0">4)<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="1">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0">4)<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="1">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0">4)<br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="group">
                <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0">1)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0">2)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0">3)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q10" value="1">4)<br>
              </div>

              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" name="submit">
              <br>
              <br>
            </form>
          </font>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <span>Тест пройден на <p>0%</p></span>
  </div>
  <div class="result1">
    <span>Вы не прошли тест!</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```